# Find the dimension of the set of all polynomials of degree at most 3, as well as the subspace consisting of symmetric and skew-symmetric polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the set of all polynomials $f(x,y)$ in $x,y$ with real coefficients, of degree at most 3. That is, each term of the polynomial will have the form $x^iy^j$ with $i,j \in \mathbb{N}$ and $i+j \leq 3$.

1. What is the dimension of V?
2. Let $V_+$ be the subspace of symmetric functions in $V$, i.e. $V_+$ is the set of all $f(x,y) \in V$ such that $f(y,x) = f(x,y)$. What is the dimension of $V_+$?
3. Let $V_-$ be the subspace of skew-symmetric functions in $V$, i.e. $V_-$ is the set of all $f(x,y) \in V$ such that $f(y,x) = -f(x,y)$. What is the dimension of $V_-$?

This is what I've done so far:

1. To find the dimension of $V$ we must find a basis of $V$ say $\mathcal{B}$. We can do this by enumerating all of the valid monomials of a polynomial in $V$. They are,
   $$ \mathcal{B} =\{x^3,y^3,x^2y,y^2x,x^2,y^2,xy,x,y,1\}.$$ Thus the dimension of $V$ is 10.
2. This is where I am not sure what I am doing is correct. We must find a basis for $V_+$. One polynomial that surely works is any constant function, so we can include $1$ in our basis for $V_+$. Now, consider the following,
   $$ x^3 + y^3 \rightarrow y^3 + x^3\\
   x^2y + y^2 x \rightarrow y^2x + x^2 y\\
   x^2 + y^2 \rightarrow y^2 x^2\\
   xy \rightarrow yx\\
   x+y \rightarrow y+x.$$
   We see that for each of these polynomials, $f(y,x) = f(x,y)$. So our basis is just $1$ and all of the binomials listed above, which implies the dimension of $V_+$ is 6.
3. Again, I'm unsure if this is correct. My basic idea was to try what I did above, but instead of adding basis vectors of $V$, subtracting. I came up with,
   $$x^3 - y^3 \rightarrow -y^3 + x^3\\
   x^2y-y^2x \rightarrow -y^2x+x^2y\\
   x^2-y^2 \rightarrow -y^2 + x^2\\
   x-y \rightarrow -y + x\\
   $$ Thus the dimension of $V_-$ is 4.

Any feedback would be welcome.

Comment: In 2, you appear to be trying to find elements stabilized by the action $x \leftrightarrow y$.  You might be happier thinking about orbit-stabilizer and Burnside's lemma in the context of your 10-element basis.
For 2 and 3: Note that every polynomial has a unique representation as the sum of a symmetric part and an antisymmetric part, so you know the sum of these two dimensions is 10.

Comment: You're missing the "anti-" in your statement of part 3 of the problem.

Comment: This link might help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524343/finding-dimension-of-the-vector-spaces-of-polynomials-with-two-commuting-variabl